# How to get attributes of a selector when using on() or bind()?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, asynchronous, bind

I have a webpage which lists some articles from a database. The content is loaded dinamically via ajax.

Each article has an edit button that will popup an editor dinamically (second ajax call) where the user can make corrections to the article.

My problem is that I need to pass the 'id' of the article when the edit button is pressed (in order to load it into the editor window), but because I need to use bind() to make the buttons work there is no way to get any atrribute of the button (selector) like 'href':

```
$('body').on ('click', '.button', function (){
       //load editor window
});
```

So how could I refrence here the '.button' to get its attributes using .attr () for example.

Thanks!

Comment: you just use `$(this).attr('href');` in your function.

Comment: Tried, but I get only the elements - $('body')'s attributes...:(

Comment: Here is a fiddle that works http://jsfiddle.net/7vuecxbx/

Comment: @cmorrissey - e.preventDefault(); made a difference! It works! Thanks, could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `e.preventDefault();` to make sure you are not firing the default event that would be the URL in your `href` tag.

```
$('body').on ('click', '.button', function (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your HTML gets rendered in this manner:

```
<div id="article_1">
    <button class="button">Edit</button>
</div>
<div id="article_2">
    <button class="button">Edit</button>
</div>
<div id="article_3">
    <button class="button">Edit</button>
</div>
```

If that's the case, then your JS should be like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I get 'undefined'. :(

Comment: in that case your HTML is not parsed the same way. Can you look at your browser's HTML inspector, and show us a copy of your article's HTML?

Comment: not parsed quite the same: <table class="listing-table">
<?php foreach($listOfExp as $value): ?>
<tr><td><a class="edit-exp" href="#" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">Edit-<?php echo $value['id']; ?></a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="position"><?php echo $value['position']; ?></td>
<td class="dates"><?php echo $value['start_date']; ?>-<?php echo $value['end_date']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>

Comment: adding: e.preventDefault(); - helped. Thanks

Comment: ahh.. youre using an anchor `<a>`. On your original question you said "button" which is why that did not come to mind. Glad you were able to solve it.